# Flask app request.get_json() return (Ellipsis, Ellipsis) instead of json

Tags: python, flask, postman

I am building a simple Flask API and I Am testing a post request from Postman,
like this `{"name": "Frosty"}` . This is my class that handles the requests to the endpoint where the POST request goes:

```
from http import HTTPStatus
from flask.views import MethodView
from flask import Blueprint
from injector import singleton, inject
from flask import jsonify, abort, request
    
    
@singleton
class PetsController(MethodView):
    @inject
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        super().__init__()
        self.pets = [
            {"id": 1, "name": "Snoopy"},
            {"id": 2, "name": "Furball"},
            {"id": 3, "name": "Alaska"},
        ]

def configure(self):
    self.pets_view = Blueprint("pets_view", __name__)
    self.pets_view.add_url_rule("/pets/", view_func=PetsController.as_view("pets"))

def get(self):
    return jsonify({"pets": self.pets})

def post(self):
    data = request.get_json()
    if not data or not "name" in data:
        return jsonify(
            message=f"Data missing from POST request {data}",
            status=HTTPStatus.BAD_REQUEST.value,
        )

    new_pet = {"id": len(self.pets) + 1, "name": data["name"]}
    self.pets.append(new_pet)
    return jsonify(
        message=f"new pet added: {new_pet}",
        status=HTTPStatus.CREATED.value,
    )
```

I am getting a bad request response because the `request.get_json()` ad `request.json` both return this tuple `(Ellipsis, Ellipsis)`.

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok it seems that was a **Postman** glitch, even though I had define in the `Headers` the `Content-Type: application/json` it was not sending that information.

I deleted and started a new `POST` request and first manually added the header and then added the `raw` body data, selected type `JSON` and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Try this. It will surely work; it's worked for me.

```
request.get_json(force=True, silent=True, cache=False)
```

P.S.: Only setting `cache=false` also worked for me.