# AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'get' while using POST request in Postman

Tags: javascript, python, flask, postman

I'm trying to use request.get_json() to add nodes from JSON data to a set.

```
@app.route('/connect_node', methods = ['POST'])

def connect_node():
    json = request.get_json()
    nodes = json.get('nodes')              
    if nodes is None:
        return "No node", 400
```

[The snapshot of the Postman POST request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JxH8J.png)

The error I'm getting in Spyder(Python 3.9):

```
line 178, in connect_node
nodes = json.get(nodes)
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'get'
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming your going though the udemy blockchain course, turns out its just a problem with the postman check this out
[Flask app request.get_json() return (Ellipsis, Ellipsis) instead of json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70239112/flask-app-request-get-json-return-ellipsis-ellipsis-instead-of-json)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using python 3.9 and getting this error then Build a virtual environment in anaconda with python 3.6 and use this python interpreter for all Spyder consoles.
It worked in my case.